# Fibonacci numbers not getting printed beyond F(996)

Tags: python

I wrote this small snippet to calculate Fibonacci numbers.  It works well for numbers up to 996 and from 997 a trace back is being printed.  I can't figure out what the problem is.  Does it has something to do with maximum_recursion_count?

```
def fib(n):
 if n==0:
  return 0
 elif n==1:
  return 1
 else:
  return fib(n-1)+n
```

Comment: You should always post the stack trace when you ask questions like this.

Comment: @Steven: If it's a stack overflow problem the traceback would be huge... but yeah, an excerpt from the end would be helpful.

Comment: This is not Fibonnaci sequence.

Comment: @David Zaslavsky: yeah, but the question basically says "a stack trace is being printed."  No mention of the error.  While we presume it's a stack overflow, nowhere do we actually see that it is...  It's a good habit to get into ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reached the maxmimum recursion depth limit. As far as I know its default value is about 1000. You can change it sys.setrecursionlimit() and see it using sys.getrecursionlimit()

Answer (score 5):

Probably. Take a look at [`sys.getrecursionlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html). The default value is 1000, which sounds like it just might be causing the problem you're seeing: once there are 1000 frames on the stack (i.e. slightly less than 1000 recursive function calls), you'll get an error on the next function call.

You can set the recursion limit to a larger value using `sys.setrecursionlimit`, but there is a maximum value which is platform-dependent (which means you might have to figure out what it is by trial and error).

Answer (score 3):

There is a wonderful Fibonnaci function implementation [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) that doesn't use recursion.

Comment: Personal Note: I have run this function in the interpreter up to 10^600 and gotten all the numbers in less than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Your code may come up against stack call limits.

Answer (score 3):

You say "It works well for numbers up to 996" ... No, it doesn't, it generates the wrong results. The last line should be:

```
return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

Comment: The problem is, this is a TERRIBLE way to compute the fibonacci numbers. It will cost O(2^n) recursive calls to compute the nth fibonacci number. So for n even as small as 50, do you really want to do that much work?

Comment: @woodchips:  On the other hand, it's at least a correct way.  If my answers don't have to be correct, I can produce them extremely fast.  This is an improvement over the original for calculating Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @woodchips: yeah yeah yeah, recursion is usually inefficient. The first priority is to get it CORRECT. How can the OP get a non-recursive function working properly when he doesn't have the relationship `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)` correct in his head? Once he has got that and verified a recursive function against manual calcs for (say) n <= 10, THEN he's in a position to start writing a non-recursive function.

Comment: @woodchips .. yeah i understand how terrible the problem is and i was trying to implement dynamic programming technique with it .so as to improve the running tym and during the testing the performance of the
improved version vs this one i got this error .